# Tensorflow version 2.6.0, cuda version=10.2 not utilizing GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, gpu

The tensorflow which I was using , is not utilizing gpu now, after it has been changed accidentally by other person. I remember that i installed my tensorflow using wheel. Currently, the version of Cuda is 10.2, python version is 3.7 and tensorflow version is 2.6.0.

The output of the following code gives me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)

**Num GPUs Available:  0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)**
```

I have attached images of my nvidia-smi command output

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sat Aug 28 14:05:15 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:21:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   43C    P8     9W / 160W |     92MiB /  5934MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     13060      C   /home/hemapriya/anaconda3/bin/python          81MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

!conda list cudatoolkit
!conda list cudnn

Output:

# packages in environment at /home/hemapriya/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0    anaconda
# packages in environment at /home/hemapriya/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0    anaconda

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

output:

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 15409823727920383739
]
```

Also, now after that incident, my tf.keras.optimizers.Adam is not working now.

Could you please let me know, how I should rectify, so that my tensorflow should include GPU.

Comment: Your TensorFlow version does not match with CUDA and cuDNN. In order to use GPU, you need to install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing incompatibility issue between Tensorflow version and CUDA, cuDNN drivers. According [Tensorflow Tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) `Tensorflow 2.6` is compatible with `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1`.

To resolve your issue either you can install `CUDA`

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1
```

or downgrade Tensorflow version to `2.3`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Num GPUs Available:  1
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

I am able to run `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` as shown below

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
var1 = tf.Variable(10.0)
loss = lambda: (var1 ** 2)/2.0       
step_count = opt.minimize(loss, [var1]).numpy()
var1.numpy()
```

Output:

```
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Pow in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op RealDiv in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Shape in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Shape in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op BroadcastGradientArgs in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op RealDiv in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sum in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Reshape in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Neg in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op RealDiv in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op RealDiv in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sum in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Reshape in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Pow in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Identity in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AddV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Cast in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Identity in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Identity in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Pow in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Pow in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sqrt in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op RealDiv in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ResourceApplyAdam in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op AssignAddVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Identity in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
9.899997
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. downgrading to tensorflow 2.3.0 worked. Now its showing gpu.